# operand must be an int register in armv8

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm64, operands, armv8

I'm working on a program in ARMv8, and when attempting to compile it using gcc, I get the error message "operand 3 must be an integer register" for the following lines of code:

```
67   mul x2, x2, 8

100  mul x16, x11, 4
117  mul x16, x11, 4

140  mul x16, x12, 4
```

Similarly, I get the error message "integer register expected in the extended/shifted operand register at operand 3"

```
66   add x2, xzr, #MAX_DIGITS

142  add x17, xzr, 1
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

AArch64 `mul` doesn't have a form that takes an immediate operand, check [the manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/The-A64-instruction-set/Data-processing-instructions/Multiply-and-divide-instructions).

See https://godbolt.org/z/79oKc6fxq for what compilers do: shift instead of mul for a power of 2, otherwise mov-immediate to a register before `mul reg,reg,reg`.  Or for a 2^n+1 constant like `9`, `add  x0, x0, x0, lsl #3`

---

`add`-immediate with `xzr` is impossible, since the same syntax compilers use for adding 1 (`add reg, reg, #1`) doesn't assemble if XZR is the source register.

For some instructions, like `add`-immediate, that register number is the stack pointer, not the zero register, so xzr isn't encodeable.  That makes sense; there are instructions that can get a small integer into a register, but adding/subtracting is something you often want on the stack pointer.

If you want to materialize a small immediate, use `mov` and let the assembler figure out which opcode to use.  If you compile a function that does `return 1;`, clang uses `mov x0, #1` for the asm source.